# Populate State Dropdown after selecting from International Telephone Input plugin Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am using International Telephone Input plugin  provided by this site:
https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input

What I need now is to know if there's a way in javascript on how can I populate my State dropdown when a user selects a country using the International Telephone Input.

here's my code:

```
<input type="tel" id="country_cellno">
<select name="state" id="state" required="">
    <option>States</option>
</select>

 /*array for States, 63 here is the countrycode*/
    var s_b = new Array();
     s_b[63]= "state1|state2";


    $(document).ready(function() {
    {  

      var countryData =$("#country_cellno").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").dialCode;

      var stateElement = document.getElementById(state);

      stateElement.length = 0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
      stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Service Provider', '');
      stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

     var state_arr = s_b[countryData].split("|");

     for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
     stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Working Example

The library that you are using ([International Telephone Input](http://jackocnr.com/intl-tel-input.html)) returns countries and dialing codes. If you want state and providence information then you will need to pull that from a different source.

The first step is to add an event handler to detect when the user selects a country. In the example it is done like this:

```
$("#phone").next(".flag-dropdown").click(function() {   
    var country = $("#phone").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").name;
    // do something with the country information

});
```

The example then makes a jsonp request to [Yahoo YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=desc+geo.states) to get a list of states for the selected country and populate a dropdown. Yet, any web service supplying the information could be used.

**Run the Code Snippet to Try**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<Title>Demo</Title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jackocnr.com/lib/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css">    
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jackocnr.com/lib/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: arial; font-size: 14px;">
 
<input id="phone" type="tel">
<select id="states"></select>
    
<script type="text/javascript">

// Initialize
$("#phone").intlTelInput({
  defaultCountry: "auto",
  utilsScript: "http://jackocnr.com/lib/intl-tel-input/lib/libphonenumber/build/utils.js" 
});
    
 
// event handler    
$("#phone").next(".flag-dropdown").click(function() {
    
    var country = $("#phone").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").name;
    country = country.split('(').shift(); // use English country name
    //console.info( country );
    var query = 'select name,woeid from geo.states where place="' + country + '" | sort(field="name")';
    var url = (
        'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' +
        encodeURIComponent( query ) + 
        '&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?'
    );
    $.getJSON( url, function( data ) { 
      setOptions('#states', data.query.results.place );
    });    
});
    
// update dropdown
function setOptions( selector, data ) {
  var $el = $( selector );
  $el.empty(); 
  if (!data) return;
  $.each( data, function( i, obj ) {
    $el.append($("<option></option>").attr( 'value', obj.name ).text( obj.name ));
  });
}

</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks! But is there any way I can connect it to an Array of States?

Comment: In new version of International Telephone Input markup changed so we need to search like this 
     `$("#phone").prev().find(".country-list").click(function() {

    var country = $("#phone").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").name;
   
 });`

Comment: @ohmyfgod - Tx for updating the change for other users.